# How to access user-defined value in a bolt's getComponentConfiguration() when using storm?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I want to initialize my redis address dynamicly by command line, And use it before a bolt's `open` method:

```
public class RunMyTopology {

  @Parameter(names = { "-topologyName"}, description = "Topology name.")
  private static String TOP_NAME = "demo";

  @Parameter(names = { "-redisAddr"}, description = "Redis host address.", validateWith = IPValidator.class)
  public static String REDIS_ADDR =  "172.16.3.142";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException {   
  new JCommander(new RunMyTopology(), args);

  TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();   
  builder.setSpout("spout", new Spout(REDIS_ADDR), 1);
  builder.setBolt("fixerBolt",new FixerBolt(REDIS_Addr),1).fieldsGrouping("spout", new Fields("busId")); 
  // And many other bolts need REDIS_ADDR
  Config conf = new Config();
  conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKERS, 22);
  StormSubmitter.submitTopology(TOP_NAME, new Conf, builder.createTopology());
   }
}
```

Now I can achive it by passing constructor parameters, but if I have many 
config values like redis address, this way looks ugly. How to notify the changed value in other way?

Comment: My question is almost the same to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009604/how-to-access-an-object-from-the-topology-context-into-a-bolt-when-using-storm?rq=1 But I need to access them before `declareOutputFields`, and my configuration is dynamic, can't be store in a static class.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic" please describe your use case. There are many ways to update configuration dynamically in Storm.

Comment: I change the description of my question, the value of REDIS_ADDR can be changed using `storm jar me.kangkona.demo-0.0.1.jar me.kangkona.demo.RunPreprocessTopology -redisAddr 172.16.3.140` by `Parameter`.  But the question is, bolts will access the default value of REDIS_ADDR insteads of the changed one in cluster model.

Comment: So it is not dynamic, you define only once your properties before your topology starts and they won't change after, what you describe seems to be externalization of properties. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, Your description is very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no externalization of properties in Apache Storm.

But you can use many librairies that are available for this purpose, such as Spring (placeholder API) or Apache Commons Configuration (I personally use it with storm as it is quite lightweight and does that job well enough).

If you plan on using Commons Configuration:

- define your property files for different environment DEV, PROD...
- you must parse a commons configuration first with support for property overwritting (with an environment or system variable for instance)
- then get all properties inside to put them into Storm Config (filter some if you take all system properties, it can be full of crap)
- finally you can start your cluster

Hope that helps.

Here is a link to the documentation.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/overview.html#Using_Configuration